# remove/delete existing from sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

I am new to sonarqube and was able diable/deactivate default rules that comes with sonar. However I would like to know if there is a way to delete/remove default rules from sonar ?

Answer (score 1):

yes of course you can disable some rules and change the level (major, minor etc) in the admin console of your sonarqube and you can use a custom quality profile with a selected rules to analyse you project
http://docs.sonarqube.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/6964603

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in as Admin.
2. Through Quality profile we will be able to activate and deactivate the default rules.
   3.Ability to create a new profile with specific rules and scan the project with this new profile.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

1. Log in as admin
2. Set another profile as default, i.e. not the one you want to remove.
3. Now the non-default profile will be deletable.